# Ember: How to set controller model for use in select view

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

See: http://jsfiddle.net/cyclomarc/VXT53/8/

I have a select view in which I simply want to list all the authors available in the fixtures data.  I therefore try to use a separate controller in which I want to set the content = App.Author.find(), but that doesn't work ...

```
App.AuthorsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  //content: App.Store.findAll(App.Author)
  //content: App.Author.find()
});
```

I then want to use the AuthorController for contentBinding in the selectView, but also this is not succsesful ...

```
{{view Ember.Select
       contentBinding="App.AuthorsController"
       optionValuePath="content.id"
       optionLabelPath="content.name" 
       valueBinding="App.PublicationsEditController.author"
       prompt="Select an author"
   }}
```

The use case is that I have a publication in which an author is set (e.g. Marc) and I want to allow the user to change this to one of the available authors and then bind the new selected author to the publication model so that after a save the new author is saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this what you are after: http://jsfiddle.net/VXT53/10/

I had to do a couple of changes, first your router map where slightly wrong, the `edit` segment had to go after the id to match your template name `pulications/edit`:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('publications', { path: '/' }, function () {
    this.route("edit", { path: "/edit/:publication_id" });
  });
});
```

Your `Ember.Select` where binding to a class instead to some content, to set it up correctly I've defined a `PublicationsEditControllet` to requiere trough the needs API access to the `AuthorsController`'s content:

```
App.PublicationsEditController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['authors'],
  ...
});
```

this is how you then use it for your select:

```
{{view Ember.Select
   contentBinding="controllers.authors.content"
   optionValuePath="content.id"
   optionLabelPath="content.name" 
   valueBinding="content.name"
   selectionBinding="selectedAuthor"
   prompt="Select an author"
}}
```

Furthermore I've created a `setupController` hook which is used to set the `AuthorsController`'s content to the list of authors:

```
App.PublicationsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return App.Publication.find();
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);
    this.controllerFor('authors').set('content', App.Author.find());
  }
});
```

And lastly on you `PublicationsEditController` is a new property attached `selectedAuthor` to hold the currently selected author for binding etc.

```
App.PublicationsEditController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  needs: ['authors'],
  selectedAuthor: null
});
```

I guess this should work now and brings you one step further.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This helped me a lot.  Was not aware that I needed to set the content of the AuthorController via the setupController in the route.  But this makes sense.  Just one minor remark: I think the PublicationsEditController should not be of the type ArrayController (results in errors in console).  Have changed it to ObjectController.  Thx. Marc

Comment: Hi @cyclomarc, glad I could help. I'll change the controller type in my answer too then...

Comment: @intuitivepixel Hi, I accessed the jsFiddle but the application fails to render.

Comment: JSfiddles dont always work with ember - it is preferable to use http://emberjs.jsbin.com/